# FB app does not add bookmark

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When any of my friends play my fb app game, they report that no bookmark gets generated.  The app appears to be configured properly in the control panel.  However, my app is a simple HTML page with a swf flash game embedded.  I have not added any of the fb sdk's.  What do I have to do?

https://apps.facebook.com/airportmadnessfour

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to authorize the user. ie: let him log into your application for a bookmark to be created.   For this you will find the [Javascript and PHP SDK's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/) very useful.
Please be aware that we as developers have no control whether the app's bookmark stays in the list (unless it is "favorited" by the user).  The list of apps in the bookmarks sidebar that are displayed depend on the usage of the user.

Comment: Thanks.  Should I use the php sdk or the JavaScript skd or both?  I don't need any permissions.

Comment: you can use any or both, what ever you feel comfortable with... and no, I do not believe that you need to request permissions. just authorize the user...

Comment: glad to hear my friend!  please mark this question as answered by clicking on the tick...